# How to find device co-ordinates with respect some point (which is calculated by the device itself) in android 4.4?

Tags: android, geolocation, android-sensors

I have followed below questions in both acceleration and location finding with reference to true north. But results are not at all accurate for device location. Could anybody tell me how to enable that TYPE_GRAVITY sensor also?

[calculate acceleration in reference to true north](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963190/calculate-acceleration-in-reference-to-true-north/14988559#14988559)

[Convert magnetic field X, Y, Z values from device into global reference frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315129/convert-magnetic-field-x-y-z-values-from-device-into-global-reference-frame/15317814#15317814)

Basically i want to know my device location(co-ordinates) with respect to some known location.

Comment: Just use bearingTo() method in the Location class.

Comment: basically for bearingTo() we have to pass location.
My question how we can accuratley calculate that location itself.

Comment: You cannot calculate location from sensors, only heading. To get device location use GPS.

Comment: GPS accuracy is very low ranges about 18 feet. i need most accurate one.

Comment: GPS is the most accurate you can get.

Comment: By using accelerometer and rotational matrix, Can i get the direction of my device with respect to some global co-ordinates( eg: a table)?

Comment: @hoan-nguyen: Thanks for your previous comments