# Implementing an accurate compass with Android

Tags: android, android-sensors, panoramas, azimuth

It's been like 2 weeks trying different ways to calculate the **azimuth** of the phone, but I've found basically two problems:

**My problems**

1. A 360º turn is not always 360º. If I do my turn quickly, I get done my 360º before the end of the turn, if I go slowly, I get done my 360º after the end of the turn.
2. The azimuth gets moved randomly when I put it laying on the table. Or even holding in the same position, for any *tick*, I get a +- 3 degrees, so if I stay with 200º and I wait, I could be 197º. And then if I keep waiting, it could reach 194º, but I'm staying.

**What am I looking for?**

For the problem **1.-**, I'm looking for a precise movement on the X axis (*azimuth*). A good example can be found in the [HelloPanoramaGL project sample](https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/). It moves smoothly and you can get the sensation you're moving a real panorama.

For the problem **2.-**, [This project based in a Panorama for iOS](https://github.com/robbykraft/Panorama) does both 1.- and 2.-. When you do a turn, it gets the same position.

**What I've tried**

Well, after 2 weeks I dare to say I've done everything I found on Internet, for example:

- Trying to set the `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` which is deprecated, but it's the one that has provided me best results.
- Trying a combination of `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` and `Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD`. Also [adding a Low Pass Filter to the Sensors](https://www.built.io/blog/2013/05/applying-low-pass-filter-to-android-sensors-readings/).
- Using the rest of the sensors like `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` to wait for any hope to make it work.

But I got my problems not solved.

**This is my current code now:**

*Declaring all sensors:*

```
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor magnetic_field;
    private Sensor accelerometer;
    private Sensor orientation;
```

*initializing onCreate():*

```
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    orientation = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
    accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    magnetic_field = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
```

*registering the listener onResume():*

```
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetic_field, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, orientation, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    // tried with SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST, SENSOR_DELAY_UI and SENSOR_DELAY_GAME
```

*and getting the results:*

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
        float azimuth1 = event.values[0];
        return;
    }

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        mGravity = event.values;
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
        mGeomagnetic = event.values;
    if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
        float R_[] = new float[9];
        float I_[] = new float[9];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R_, I_, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
        if (success) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R_, orientation);
            azimut = orientation[0]; // orientation contains: azimut, pitch and roll
        }
    }
}
```

If you could help me with that it would be great.

Thank you very much.

Regards.

Rafael.

Comment: Isn't this an answer to your question: *http://stackoverflow.com/a/16398113/192373*?

Comment: It is, I totally forgot to answer myself